# How to reset a Drop-Down when user changes the parent Drop-Down?

Tags: vba, ms-word

My boss wants me to make a form in MS Word for the user to request access to a shared drive based on their department. The form has three drop-down depended on one parent drop-down, so when the user selects a department the child drop-downs just show the shared drives that are for that specific department. 
I have written it but the problem is after they choose an option in any of the child drop-downs and then changed the parent, the child still is there, which is wrong. how can I reset the child drop-downs when the parent one is changed?
here is my code

```
Public xDivision As FormField

Sub ConditionalDrives()
    Dim xDrives As FormField
    Set xDivision = ActiveDocument.FormFields("ddDivisions")
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xDrives = ActiveDocument.FormFields("ddDrives")
    If ((xDivision Is Nothing) And (xDrives Is Nothing)) Then Exit Sub
        With xDrives.DropDown.ListEntries
            Select Case xDivision.Result
                Case "Admin"
                    .Clear
                    .Add "(F:) \\SHEARDDRIVE1\ADMIN"
                    .Add "(H:) \\SHEARDDRIVE2(Confidential Staff)"
                    .Add "(N:) \\SHEARDDRIVE3(Personnel)"
                Case "IT"
                    .Clear
                    .Add "(F:) \\SHEARDDRIVE1"
                    .Add "(Y:) \\SHEARDDRIVE2"
                Case "HR"
                    .Clear
                    .Add "(F:) \\HRSHEARDDRIVE"
                    .Add "(M:) \\SHEARDDRIVE2"
            End Select
        End With
 End Sub

Sub ConditionalDrives2()
    Dim xDrives2 As FormField
    Set xDrives2 = ActiveDocument.FormFields("ddDrives2")
        With xDrives2.DropDown.ListEntries
            Select Case xDivision.Result
                Case "Admin"
                    .Clear
                    .Add "(F:) \\SHEARDDRIVE1\ADMIN"
                    .Add "(H:) \\SHEARDDRIVE2(Confidential Staff)"
                    .Add "(N:) \\SHEARDDRIVE3(Personnel)"
                Case "IT"
                    .Clear
                    .Add "(F:) \\SHEARDDRIVE1"
                    .Add "(Y:) \\SHEARDDRIVE2"
                Case "HR"
                    .Clear
                    .Add "(F:) \\HRSHEARDDRIVE"
                    .Add "(M:) \\SHEARDDRIVE2"
            End Select
        End With
End Sub
Sub ConditionalDrives3()
    Dim xDrives3 As FormField
    Set xDrives3 = ActiveDocument.FormFields("ddDrives3")
        With xDrives3.DropDown.ListEntries
             Select Case xDivision.Result
                Case "Admin"
                    .Clear
                    .Add "(F:) \\SHEARDDRIVE1\ADMIN"
                    .Add "(H:) \\SHEARDDRIVE2(Confidential Staff)"
                    .Add "(N:) \\SHEARDDRIVE3(Personnel)"
                Case "IT"
                    .Clear
                    .Add "(F:) \\SHEARDDRIVE1"
                    .Add "(Y:) \\SHEARDDRIVE2"
                Case "HR"
                    .Clear
                    .Add "(F:) \\HRSHEARDDRIVE"
                    .Add "(M:) \\SHEARDDRIVE2"
            End Select
        End With
End Sub
```

Comment: There's some information missing... What triggers the code posted in the question? On Exit, On Enter of form fields? Something else? My inclincation is to say, clear those other drop-downs On Enter for the parent...

Comment: I meant when the user changes the department, the drive dropdown should get clear.

Comment: Well, form fields can't do anything when a selection is made. The only actions they have are OnEnter and OnExit. So code to re-set the drive dropdown would need to be run by the department field's On Exit property.